# Use MudSelect in MudTable

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I would like to use MudSelect in MudTable:

```
<MudTable ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<PlatformListResponseModel>>>(TableDataLoading))" Loading="isLoading" Hover="true" @ref="PlatformListTable">
            <HeaderContent>
                <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortLabel="platformName" T="PlatformListResponseModel">Platform Name</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
                <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortLabel="platformStatus" T="PlatformListResponseModel">Platform Status</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
                <MudTh></MudTh>
            </HeaderContent>

            <RowTemplate>
                <MudTd>@context.platformName (@context.platformID)</MudTd>
                <MudTd>
                    <MudSelect T="int" Value="context.platformStatus" ValueChanged="@((int selectedValue) => HandlePlatformStatus(selectedValue, context.platformStatus))">
                        <MudSelectItem Value="0">Open</MudSelectItem>
                        <MudSelectItem Value="1">Close</MudSelectItem>
                        <MudSelectItem Value="2">Maintain</MudSelectItem>
                    </MudSelect>
                </MudTd>
                <MudTd>
                    <MudButton>More</MudButton>
                </MudTd>
            </RowTemplate>

            <NoRecordsContent>
                <MudText>No Data!</MudText>
            </NoRecordsContent>

            <PagerContent>
                <MudTablePager />
            </PagerContent>
        </MudTable>
```

I will call API when the select is changed so I use ValueChanged to call event fuction.
If I set Value in MudSelect, When changing the select item, it won't change on display.
And I want to check the api service respons if I change success.

I would like to know, how to set the MudSelect to get origin value in MudTable and could to change on display?
And if changing success the block will display new one, and if changing fail the block will display origin one.

Is there any way to change select display without table data reload?

Comment: You could improve your question by showing a more complete example. What is the code doing. What code have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
<MudTd>
    <MudSelect T="int" Value="context.platformStatus" ValueChanged="@((int selectedValue) => HandlePlatformStatus(selectedValue, context))">
        <MudSelectItem Value="0">Open</MudSelectItem>
        <MudSelectItem Value="1">Close</MudSelectItem>
        <MudSelectItem Value="2">Maintain</MudSelectItem>
    </MudSelect>
</MudTd>
...

@code {
    private async Task HandlePlatformStatus(int selectedValue, PlatformListResponseModel context)
    {
        // call api and get result

        if (result.IsSuccess)
        {
            context.platformStatus = selectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```